# Java for each loop working

Tags: java, loops, foreach

I was working on certain task, **when incidentally did something wrong according to me** but the code executed and provided correct result. I was little surprised and had question in mind how all these for each loop works.
Example (sample program),

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String myInput = "hello , hi , how are you ";
    String[] splitted = myInput.split(",");
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String output : splitted) 
    {
        mylist.add(output);
    }


    for (String output : mylist) 
    {
        System.out.println(output);
        mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); //It worked 
        mylist.add(output);
    }

    for (String output : splitted) 
    {
        mylist.add(output);
    }

    for (String output : mylist) 
    {
        System.out.println(output);             
        mylist.add(output); // After this line it threw exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    }

}
```

I was curious to know and while searching I found one more post that said we can remove elements from list if we used iterator approach, So I tried,

```
for (String output : splitted) 
{
    mylist.add(output);
}
for (Iterator iterator2 = mylist.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();)
{
    String string = (String) iterator2.next();
    System.out.println(string);
    iterator2.remove(); //It worked but if I used the same thing to remove element from original list it threw exception.
}
```

Now I just want to know what is happening behind the every for each loop quoted above.
**I want to know the technical aspect, I know I can not modify the collection in for each loop but in some case stated above it worked why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I just want to know what is happening behind the every for each
>   loop quoted above

```
 1. for (String output : splitted) 
    {
        mylist.add(output);
    }
```

This adds each `output` String from `splitted` array to the `mylist` list.

```
2. for (String output : mylist) 
{
      System.out.println(output);
      mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); //It worked 
      mylist.add(output);
}
```

The `for` statement is governed by the following production:

```
for ( FormalParameter : Expression )
            Statement
```

where `Expression` must be an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`, or an array. So this `for:each` loop is equivalent to this:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = mylist.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(output);
    mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); //It worked 
    mylist.add(output);
}
```

Here `mylist.iterator()` will return a new instance of `Iterator` type:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
}
```

So even if you are creating new `ArrayList` instances and assigning them to `mylist` on each iteration, the iterator obtained from the original `mylist` will still have a reference to the original `mylist` and will keep iterating through the elements of original `mylist`. The iterator keeps a reference to the list it was created on. The assignment `mylist = new ArrayList<String>()` has no effect on the data that the iterator works on because it changes the variable `mylist` and not the `list` itself.

```
3. for (String output : mylist) 
    {
        System.out.println(output);             
        mylist.add(output); // After this line it threw exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    }
```

Below statement explains this behavior. It is copied from `Arraylist` doc:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

```
4. for (Iterator iterator2 = mylist.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();)
{
    String string = (String) iterator2.next();
    System.out.println(string);
    iterator2.remove(); //It worked but if I used the same thing to remove element from original list it threw exception.
}
```

The above statement also explains the behavior of this for loop: the `list` can be structurally modified by the  iterator's own remove or add methods while iterating through the list.

Comment: You should probably add that the second loop works because the iterator keeps a reference to the list it was created on.  The assignment `mylist = new ArrayList<String>()` has no effect on the data that the iterator works on because it changes the variable `mylist` and not the list itself.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert Agree. edited my answer: copied your statement.

Answer (score 2):

A for-each loop is possible for Classes that implement [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). This also means that you can create Classes yourself which you can use in for-each loops, which can be very comfortable.

This interface forces you to implement a method `iterator()` which returns an `Iterator`. Then the for-each loop does nothing but retrieve that iterator and iterate over it using `hasNext()` and `next()`. Just the same as you would do it yourself.

The problem with removing is that when you use a for-each loop and then remove an element from the List, the constructed `Iterator` will not know anything about that change and there will be a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

But if you call `Iterator.remove()` directly, the Iterator will know about that change and can handle it.

A common little trick to avoid Iterators and Exceptions at the same time is to do something like this:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Object object : new ArrayList<Object>(objects)) {
    objects.remove(object);
}
```

So you create a temporary copy of that List, iterate over that, but call remove on the original List.

Comment: Creating this copy is stupid. Just traversing the ArrayList using the iterator instead (which you do anyways, because thats what the foreach does), allows you to add and remove items without any error and without having to create a copy. And if you _do_ need to do that concurrently, there is a concurrent list for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @TwoThe We live in the year 2013. Creating a copy of a List is no problem in 99% of all cases. I think it is easier to read than using an Iterator and in those cases I like to use this trick. If you think it's stupid, okay, don't use it. I also saw it as a further explanation of the problem described in the question...

Comment: It is a completely useless operation that in addition circumvents the warning mechanism in Java called the ConcurrentModificationException. So it is not only unnecessary but as well hides potential bugs. Why use something like that if there is an easy-as-pie alternative?

Comment: How does this introduce any possible bugs? It is a perfectly valid solution, with the only disadvantage that a copy is created.

Answer (score 2):

**for-each loop** of List will be internally converted to **for loop with iterator**.

```
  for (String output : mylist) 
      {
          System.out.println(output);
          mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); //It worked 
          mylist.add(output);
      }
```

gets converted to

```
   for (Iterator<String> iterator = mylist.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String output = (String)iterator.next();
        System.out.println(output);
        mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); //It worked 
        mylist.add(output); 
      }
```

And since the the snapshot of list is already taken at below

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = mylist.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
```

The loop is running until the last element of list i.e. "how are you".

Whereas, below is not working because of [FailFast behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of List.

```
for (String output : mylist) 
    {
        System.out.println(output);             
        mylist.add(output); // After this line it threw exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    }
```

It says, if you are modifying the list while iterating, with anything other than iterator's own remove method, List will throw ConcurrentModificationException and thats the reason the below is working.

```
for (Iterator iterator2 = mylist.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();)
{
    String string = (String) iterator2.next();
    System.out.println(string);
    iterator2.remove(); //It worked but if I used the same thing to remove element from original list it threw exception.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is corrent. You cannot modify value of collection that is beeing iterated over using "foreach" loop, and to do that, you have to use collection's iterator.

Answer (score 0):

It is of course not a problem to add something to a completely different list than the one you are currently traversing, as you did with the line `mylist = new ArrayList<String>();` Even though the variable still has the same name, it will point to an entirely different list.

The reason why you cannot add something to a list that is currently being "walked through" is, that the internal implementation of that list might not be able to ensure, that you still get the same order of elements and especially not all remaining elements as you would expect.
This can be understand best if you imagine that you are using a sorted list: you put in a new element, but whether or not you see that element is undefined, as it depends on where you are and what you insert. As Java doesn't know if you are ok with that, it takes the safe road and throws an Exception.

There are however lists that are well capable of being able to be modified during traversal, mostly the concurrent lists in the [concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).